# How to install tomcat with a specific PATH under Windows?

Tags: windows, tomcat, service

I have the following Code:

```
tomcat5.exe //IS//%SERVICE_NAME% --StartPath "%BASE_DIR%\bin" --Jvm "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\%JAVA_MODE%\jvm.dll" --StartClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StopClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StartParams "-config;%CONFIG%;start" --StopParams stop --Startup auto 
tomcat5.exe //US//%SERVICE_NAME% --JvmOptions "-Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE%#-Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%#-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%CATALINA_HOME%\common\endorsed#-Xrs#-Djava.library.path=%DLL_DIR%#-DimageservicePath=%imageservicePath%" --StartMode jvm --StopMode jvm
tomcat5.exe //US//%SERVICE_NAME% ++JvmOptions "-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp"
tomcat5.exe //US//%SERVICE_NAME% --JvmMx %MEMORY% --JvmMs %MIN_MEMORY%
tomcat5.exe //US//%SERVICE_NAME% --Environment "PATH=.\;c:\path\bin"
```

I need to specify a special PATH, because some native-code loading issues.

My problem is, that the service-installer will change provided PATH:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html

> --Environment
>   List of environment variables that will be provided to the service in the form key=value. They are separated using either # or ***;*** characters

I need to specify a Windowes PATH with two locations: `PATH=.;c:\path\bin`
The path will be stored within the registry:

```
PATH=.
c:\path\bin
```

it should be:

```
PATH=.;c:\path\bin
```

It works as described, so I think I missed something, but I did not find anything about how to set the PATH and solve this issue...

PS:
I know I'm using an outdated version of tomcat.

Comment: Can you edit the .bat script that starts Tomcat?

Comment: The tomcat is started as windows-service not via a *.bat. But I can change all Scripts if needed.

Comment: You mentioned that you want the PATH to be PATH=.;c:\path\bin but the command you are running is 
  tomcat5.exe //US//%SERVICE_NAME% --Environment "PATH=.\;bin"


  Also, since this is a service, you might want to add the full path instead of ".". Are you receiving an error when you run the above command ?

Comment: Was a typo ... the problem seems to be, that the apache serviceinstaller splits the --Environment parameter at the ';' sign. So I am unable to provide a windows PATH this way, because the windows path-seperator is ; as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after I downloaded the source and figured out, that the apache-commons procrun deamon is used and I finally found the solution. The documentation at the tomcat project wasn't complete:

http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html

> ++Environment
>   List of environment variables that will be provided to the service in the form key=value. They are separated using either # or ; characters. **If you need to embed either # or ; character within a value put them inside single quotes.**

The last sentence lead to the solution:

> "%EXECUTABLE%" //US//%SERVICE_NAME% --Environment "PATH='%PATH%'"

Comment: Thank you! :) To others, the quotes around PATH are important to handle existing paths with <space> characters in them (otherwise the PATH will be incomplete)

Comment: @SverrirSigmundarson It is 2019 and not 2090 ... space characters in PATH-variable aren't fixed yet :)

Comment: Lol, amen brother! ;)